# Facebook Leadgen does not send Webhook Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I've an app which collects leads generated using Facebook Leadgen Ad.
I've a Webhook subscribed for that but for some reason it never sends any requests when leadgen form is filled.

Earlier it was working without any issues.
I noticed yesterday that I received request an hour after forms were filled whereas today I've not received any requests but I do see new leads in the CSV file I downloaded.

Will appreciate if somebody can point me to what can be going wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware of this currently open bug report from the homepage of Facebook's Platform Bug Tracker? It might be affecting your webhooks:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786071381523903/

Comment: Hi, I just saw that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @AshitVora Are you able to make this working?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have come across this but, there is a testing tool which you can use to submit test leads for a page and see if the lead is getting pushed to your app successfully or not -

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing?__mref=message_bubble

If you click on the Track Status button after creating test lead it tell you the status of the webhook ping for the submitted lead.